# Take a screenshot of device from my app

Tags: android, screenshot

I need to make the screenshot of the screen of my device even if my application is in the background. 
I tried with the following code, but I just get the screenshot of the screen of my app even if it is in the background.

```
View rootview = v.getRootView();
rootview.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
Bitmap bmp = rootview.getDrawingCache();
```

Do you have any method or library to suggest?

Comment: so you want to spy on the screen of the user ?

Comment: I hope this is not possible

Comment: eheheheh...would seem a violation of privacy, but it is only for non-commercial educational app!

Comment: There are several apps that allow you to make the screenshot of the screen, so I thought it was a feature possible!

Comment: Yes, I have seen apps which takes the screenshot of the current screen. Try the different methods present in [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2661536/how-to-programatically-take-a-screenshot-on-android) link..

Comment: You can take a screenshot of your own application but fortunately not of others apps.